# Java populate test cases of mix types

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to create a list of test cases. Each test case contains values of different types: String and Float. Test cases don't necessarily have the same length.

Right now. I'm storing all the test cases in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. I populate the test cases like this:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> testCases = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "R1.1, R1.2, R2.1", "S", "2", "4"));
testCases.add(test1);
// the same for other test cases
```

Is there a more efficient way to populate 10 or so test cases. For example:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> testCases = new ArrayList<>(
  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "R1.1, R1.2, R2.1", "S", "2", "4")),
  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2", "R1.1, R1.2, R2.1", "T", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
)
```

Comment: what is the source of this data you use for tests ?

Comment: It's a test suite table provided in a doc.

Answer (score 0):

To handle that issue, I will use Parameterized Tests. Why ? You have so much data to test so one approach could be to create enum representing values of each list based on your own criterias then use @EnumSource of JUnit to inject these values. This link will help you to do that: https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

This example from Baeldung tests all the values from  enum Month

```
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(Month.class) // passing all 12 months
void getValueForAMonth_IsAlwaysBetweenOneAndTwelve(Month month) {
    int monthNumber = month.getValue();
    assertTrue(monthNumber >= 1 && monthNumber <= 12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to avoid `ArrayList` and use the easier `List.of` to form the set of sub-lists:

```
List<List<String>> testCases = List.of(
   List.of("1", "R1.1, R1.2, R2.1", "S", "2", "4"),
   List.of("2", "R1.1, R1.2, R2.1", "T", "5", "6", "7", "8")
);
```

Note that the above lists are immutable.